# New Light fixture with 7 bulbs

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

My electrician installed a new light fixture that has 7 LED bulbs. The bulbs hadn't arrived yet. They arrived today and when I put the first one in, it lit but as soon as I added the second neither one worked any more.  I installed all 7 and was hoping they'd eventually all come on but did not. I took them out and started again and the same thing happened. Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: Did you try turning off the switch before putting the lights in?

Comment: Sounds to me like  you're getting just enough current that one bulb can power itself but more can't. If there's a dimmer, turn it up closer to full brightness. If there isn't a dimmer, I'd start worrying about a bad connection.

Comment: Well, the electrician should be back to fix this, but a couple of tests might help. Can you cycle all 7 of the bulbs through the first (working) spot to see that they all function individually? And can you find enough incandescent bulbs to try and see if this is something quirky with the switch and leds?